# what is the best way to extend with orange hrm with symfony code?

Tags: php, symfony1

I am new to open source n have to extend oramge hrm , what to do ..? Please help where to find tutorial to work on orange hrm with symfony.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a quick look at Orange as i had not heard of it before and indeed it is built on symfony and doctrine but i have no idea which version, probably 1.4 but thats a guess.

At a glance it dow not look very open, the community version is a subset of the "live" version and i could find little if any documentation on how you would customise it. There is a big emphasis on buying it and paying for development work. A lot of what looks like technical documentation point to the php site and the apache site etc.

The wiki and the forums do not seem to deal with how you would actually customise and build modules and any references to API's i could find were generated by third parties not by Orange and the few tutorials were about customising an installed application by configuration rather then by development.

(All the above is my opinion after a bit of digging so i am prepared to be corrected).

If you are both new to open sourse and OrangeCMS and php and Symfont then you may well have asteep hill to climb. Perhpas you should check if your old job is still open.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. wtever you have commented is exactly true ... I am just not able to find any documentation till now .. I hope God has to help me now in retaining this job cuz i ma clueless where to start from..

Comment: My colleages asked me to support him on new features. Googling for several hours and I realized that there's no online documentation available for developer. Just like I'm walking into into a long dark road...